# Взаимодействие с реестром C++ (редактирование)

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу сделать программку, которая меняет имя пк. Нашел, что можно это делать через реестр WINDOWS. Посмотрел в инете подобную инфу, но ничего не нашел. Нашел вот это(ниже прикреплю).
Хочу, чтобы программа меняла значения в реестре, например имя пк 1, а программа меняла на рандомное значение (рандомайзер я сделал).
`HKEY hkey;

```
LONG error = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName", 
    NULL,
KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_QUERY_VALUE,
    &hkey);
if (error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    unsigned char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD bufferSize = MAX_PATH;
    LONG result = RegQueryValueEx(
        hkey,
        L"ComputerName",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        (LPBYTE)&buffer, &bufferSize);
    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "The reg \'LongPathsEnabled\' setup to value =" << buffer << "\n";
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Error:" << result << "\n";
    }

}
return 0;`
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что для этого нужны права администратора...

Comment: Для этого есть функция [SetComputerNameW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setcomputernamew).